# How to validate first_name instead of last_name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to check first_name value is exist (if last_name is exist only)?
if i keep first_name blank and last_name is enter .. show the error in the first_name . If the last_name is blank then not show the error

below is the  html and the validation script

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="">
        <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<a id="docs" href="http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation" target="_blank">Validation Documentation</a>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            first_name:{ required:true },
            last_name:{ required:true }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: explain properly what do want????

Comment: if i keep first_name blank and last_name is enter .. show the error in the first_name . If the last_name is empty then not show the error

Comment: simply keep validation in first_name only

Comment: need to alert only when lastname is exist

Comment: see the last example in this link http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method#dependency-expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
       $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                first_name:{ 
                    required: {
                       depends: function(element) {
                            return $('#last_name').val().length > 0;
                        }
                       }
                    } 
                },
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });
```